# Can't boot into ubuntu. Have Windows installed on one HD an ubuntu on the other

Tags: boot, windows, hard-drive

I decided to put Ubuntu on my old PC that is running windows xp, I found an old HD laying around, formatted it and installed Ubuntu. I wanted to make them separate so I installed in completely separate on the "new" HD. Now when I turn on the computer it goes straight to windows. How do I get the choice to boot into Ubuntu?

Comment: I dont think you can seperately install on 2 HDDs and then just put them up together.
I guess you will have to first put them up together and then they will be treated as a single harddisk and then you can install both.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to mess around with the bootloaders.  I would look into installing Grub on the main HD.  Perhaps making the ubuntu hardrive the primary drive.  And then manually editing the grub config (via the command, not gediting the file) so grub is aware of the windows partitions on the other HD

Comment: Grub is (IMHO) much more dynamic and configurable then windows boot.ini file